# Way to zoom image in ImageView which has certain size?

Tags: android, image

There's an ImageView with certain size (100dp, 100dp). And there's an image which size is 1000-1000px.
That's how it looks right now:
[1](http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2019/05/14/0000/2169/18553/53/b4fb706fc7.jpg)
What i want is:
[2](http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2019/05/14/0000/2169/18553/53/e4915097a4.jpg)

So image wont come out of ImageView's borders and will be sort of zoomed to center in some value, that i can change. Can it be done in some way? Maybe i need something different from ImageView? At the moment, i use adapter for recyclerview, which loads list of items that contain an image that needs to be kinda zoomed.

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cart_item_image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/min" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 just add android:scaleType="centerCrop"

here is the code look like:
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cart_item_image"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Comment: Didn't work, but changing android:background to android:src then adding android:scaleType="center" has made something alike to what i need, can i regulate zoom?